# Create a heading for groups in SP2013

Tags: list

I have a list that I am wanting to create headings and subheadings for groupings under. I don't have SP designer or infopath and am very new to Sharepoint and programming in general. If anyone could help me figure a way to do this in leyman's terms I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done out of the box.

In the ribbon, if you select Modify this view, it will take you to the view configuration. Theere is a section titled Group by. You set your desired grouping options and click OK. You will get redirected back to your view and you'll see the items grouped as you specified.

As a tip, if the coulmns you are going to group on are in the list fields, I typically remove those so you aren't looking at duplicate data.

Answer (score 0):

As @Eric told, you can Group the items by modifying the view. But SharePoint 2013 allows you to group only by two columns at a time by default.

Check this [link](http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2012/02/sharepoint-group-by-year-or-month-in.html) to learn how it is done.